# Fotorama - change nav arrows in navigation?

Tags: magento2, php, magento2.3, fotorama, fotorama-slider

I need my gallery to look like this:

[image: Fotorama Gallery]

I struggle to find out, how I can change the navigation so that the arrows are not overlapping the thumbnails:

[image: Navigation Now]

It should be more like this:

[image: Navigation how I need it to be]

and how can I change the arrow icons?

The template where the gallery is showing is here:

**vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\view\gallery.phtml**

```
<?php
    $images = $block->getGalleryImages()->getItems();
    $mainImage = current(array_filter($images, function ($img) use ($block) {
        return $block->isMainImage($img);
    }));

    if (!empty($images) && empty($mainImage)) {
        $mainImage = $block->getGalleryImages()->getFirstItem();
    }

    $helper = $block->getData('imageHelper');
    $mainImageData = $mainImage ?
        $mainImage->getData('medium_image_url') :
        $helper->getDefaultPlaceholderUrl('image');
?>

<div class="gallery-placeholder _block-content-loading" data-gallery-role="gallery-placeholder">
    <img
        alt="main product photo"
        class="gallery-placeholder__image"
        src="<?= /* @noEscape */ $mainImageData ?>"
    />
</div>

<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "[data-gallery-role=gallery-placeholder]": {
            "mage/gallery/gallery": {
                "mixins":["magnifier/magnify"],
                "magnifierOpts": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getMagnifier() ?>,
                "data": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getGalleryImagesJson() ?>,
                "options": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getGalleryOptions()->getOptionsJson() ?>,
                "fullscreen": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getGalleryOptions()->getFSOptionsJson() ?>,
                "breakpoints": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getBreakpoints() ?>
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

There is only some javascript where some options are passed as JSON object.

You can change the options here in the file:

**vendor\magento\theme-frontend-luma\etc\view.xml**

```
    <!-- Gallery and magnifier theme settings. Start -->
    <var name="gallery">
        <var name="nav">thumbs</var> <!-- Gallery navigation style (false/thumbs/dots) -->
        <var name="loop">true</var> <!-- Gallery navigation loop (true/false) -->
        <var name="keyboard">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off keyboard arrows navigation (true/false) -->
```

...

Here is a [list of all options](https://fotorama.io/docs/4/options/) which you can pass.
(Not all options are supported by magento by default though, you have to extend the block class `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\GalleryOptions` to add support for the missing options)

But I can't find a way to change the thumbnail nav arrow icon or change the position of them.

Do I have to write a hacky JS/CSS workaround, or is it possible to do this by changing options?

PS: Of course I did all the changes in my own theme, and not in the core.

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the mage/gallery/gallery.js file you can see that Magento uses a mage/gallery/gallery.html template. I think you can move the position of the arrows but also with CSS remove the absolute position of these.

I hope I've helped you